# Forced to work with a Geometry with too many edges in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry, features

I want to perform an unsupervised classification on a feature collection that has many small geometries.
I know it will create problems for GEE to work on such many small geometries but I cannot find a way around it.
I have to consider only this geometry because I know there are only 3 kinds of forests in this area and I can choose 3 classes for my classification, so I cannot consider the whole area.

I have tried things like ***simplify({maxError: 100}*** and  performing an intersection, but I got the error for any layer I try to map :

> MEAN_Summer_IC: Layer error: Collection.geometry: Geometry has too
> many edges (2739216 > 2000000)

Can I work with the asset 'Plot'?
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d3da6db88b9d9fcc689519525024d941

Comment: Hi, could you make your asset ForestPlantation public so that other users can run the code? Currently it's not available.

Comment: FYI, not a complete answer: you ask about many small geometries, but the error you are getting is because something in your script is converting them into *one large geometry*. That's what you need to avoid.

Comment: @M.Nicolas Thanks Nicholas. I made it public now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @KevinReid thanks, Yes it actaully one very large polygone with many edges. A shapefile of classified land cover class

Answer (score 0):

I see several ways in which your code can be optimized relative to `Plot` so that it'll run without problems.

- First, and very importantly, you must avoid clipping images (and especially imageCollections) unless strictly necessary. When doing `.map(function(image){return image.clip(Plot)});` you are increasing computation time and memory. Read more on this [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#if-you-dont-need-to-clip,-dont-use-clip). Instead, `filterBounds()` (which you are already using) or `clipToCollection()` are good alternatives, though you may need to use `Plot.union()` when using `filterBounds()` instead of just using `Plot`, not sure this is best practice though.
- Second, generally speaking, if you are struggling to simplify your geometry in GEE, you can [use QGIS](https://geoscape.com.au/knowledge-base/using-geoscape-data/simplifying-a-polygon-with-qgis-3/) instead and then re-upload your asset, though this might not be necessary.
- Finally, aside from filtering the bounds of your imageCollection, I see no reason why you need to use `Plot`; if in the future you need to get results  for that area specifically (e.g. a mean NDVI value), you will need to use `reduceRegion` but do check out [how to use it in the case of complex geometries](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#dont-use-a-complex-collection-as-the-region-for-a-reducer).

Overall, I suggest you read through [Coding Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices), since they adress many of the issues you have here.